# How do I write an on_click event method that will set an arbitrary value to a textbox?

Tags: python, oop, textbox, pyqt4

I'm trying to set some text to a textbox via button click.

Any clarification on how to tie these objects together would be greatly appreciated.

```
 def initUI(self):
        calculateBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Calculate", self)
        calculateBtn.clicked.connect(self.calculate_btn_on_click)
        earningsTextbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.show()

 def calculate_btn_on_click(self, event):
        earningsTextbox.setText("42")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add self..

```
def initUI(self):
        calculateBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Calculate", self)
        calculateBtn.clicked.connect(self.calculate_btn_on_click)
        self.earningsTextbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.show()

 def calculate_btn_on_click(self):
        self.earningsTextbox.setText("42")
```